# 'Class java.time.LocalDate cannot be cast to class java.lang.Number' with logicalType as date and type as int in Avro while saving in parquet

Tags: java, apache-flink, parquet, avro

I am trying to save a field present in Avro which is having Date logical type, in parquet output (It works when using int as datatype to save but gives error when trying to save as Date logical type). I am attempting this from a Flink application. For the type of this field, I have set as logicalType to Date and type to int.

The avro version is 1.11.1 and in the JSON I am using to generate the avro, the field is as below:

```
{
"name" : "Date",
"type": [
{"type": "int" , "logicalType": "date" }, 
"null" ]
}
```

And this field is being set in the below code:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/MM/yyyy");
String date = "16/08/2016";
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);
myAvroObject.setDate(localDate);
```

For writing the parquet output, from the Flink application, I am using the below code:

```
AvroParquetWriters.forGenericRecord(new myAvroClass().getSchema());
```

While trying to save the parquet output, it gives ClassCast exception saying 'Class java.time.LocalDate cannot be cast to class java.lang.Number'

The below thread has similarity in terms of error message but I did not find any relevant answer/comment. [Avro logicalType for Date is giving exception : java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.Date cannot be cast to class java.lang.Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76324003/avro-logicaltype-for-date-is-giving-exception-java-lang-classcastexception-cl)

Also checked this thread but didn't find a relevant solution : [how to create date type column in parquet file with parquet-avro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46364043/how-to-create-date-type-column-in-parquet-file-with-parquet-avro?rq=2)

What can be the solution for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From AVRO docs:

*The date logical type represents a date within the calendar, with no reference to a particular time zone or time of day.
A date logical type annotates an Avro int, where the int stores the number of days from the unix epoch, 1 January 1970 (ISO calendar).*

Try this

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/MM/yyyy");
String date = "16/08/2016";
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);
int daysSinceEpoch = (int) localDate.toEpochDay();

myAvroObject.setDate(daysSinceEpoch);
```

Comment: Thanks. On trying this, since it gives compilation error "SetDate(java.time.LocalDate cannot be applied to int. I tried ```myAvroObject.setDate(LocalDate.ofEpocDay(daysSinceEpoch))``` but it gave the same error saying localDate cannot be cast to number.

Comment: based on ```myAvroObject.setDate(LocalDate.ofEpocDay(daysSinceEpoch))``` , the error sounds ok. You need the int value of the method. Try  (int) localDate.toEpochDay();

Comment: But the setter is expecting type java.time.LocalDate instead of int, and in the snippet which you pasted above it is trying to set int type.  That is the setter in avro which got generated by the JSON snippet that I pasted in the original question for the field date having type int and logicalType date. Does that snippet require change so that it expects int instead of localDate?

Comment: I see. But then I dont understand why you receive an error for this ```myAvroObject.setDate(LocalDate.ofEpocDay(daysSinceEpoch))```. ofEpochDay returns LocalDate so if your setter wants Localdate as setDate param it should be fine.

Comment: what kind of generator do you use?

Comment: I am using java -jar avro-tools -1.11.1.jar command to generate avro from json.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254504/discussion-between-csisanyi-and-saurabh-rana).